# Alternative Ajax Type POST Through GET Method Not Work

Tags: php

I am quite keen to use this widget in my blog. This script will search for keywords in the content of my blog without having to switch pages.

However, I was thinking what if I add a search feature with a GET method. For example, by visiting `domain.com/page-search.php?search=keyword` instantly get the appropriate content.

I have tried to replace the `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"` in the script, but to no avail. If I use jQuery auto submit `$("test").Submit();` it works, but will switch to move the page. So I consider how it still failed.

I hope my question is clear. This is an example of my script using AJAX http://britha.com/iklan/cari.php?search=murah

Thank you ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".search_button").click(function() {
        var searchString    = $("#search_box").val();
        var data            = 'search='+ searchString;
        if(searchString) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchResult.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(html) {
                    $("#results").html(''); 
                    $(".mySearch").html(searchString);
               },
               success: function(html){
                    $("#results").show();
                    $("#results").append(html);
              }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="container">
<div id="box_cari">
<form id="test" method="post" action="searchResult.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="search_button" /><br />
</form>
</div>      
<div>

<div id="results"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution to this problem.
I change this code:

```
$(".search_button").click(function() {
```

Being:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

    $osearch = $_GET['search'];

echo "var control = $(document).ready";
}
else {
echo "var control = $('.search_button').click";
}
?>
control(function() {
```

AND add value is in the search:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box' value="<?php echo htmlentities($osearch, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off getting `$_GET['search']` in your `php` script, processing the request and displaying the results in the served html directly, but since you seem to be asking how to do it with ajax on the client side:

The below would be a more appropriate way to accomplish your goal. Pay close attention to the `encodeURIComponent()` bit, **if you dont add this, it WILL bite you later**

```
$(function() {
  var search = getQueryVariable('search'); // on load, check for search var in URL
  if (search != 'not found') {
    getSearchResult(search);
  }

  $(".search_button").click(function() { // on click, check for search var in input
    var search = $("#search_box").val();
    if (search != '') getSearchResult(search);
    return false;
  });
});

function getSearchResult(searchString) {
  var $results = $("#results").html('');
  $(".mySearch").html(searchString);
  var data = 'search=' + encodeURIComponent(searchString); // make sure you encode this, otherwise characters like & will muck up the querystring!
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "searchResult.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(html) {
      $results.html(html).show();
    }
  });
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) { // function to retreive GET var from URL
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
  }
  return 'not found';
}
```

Comment: This is in accordance with what I expected. Perfect. Thank @DelightedD0D

Comment: Thanks. Your code is correct for me. But if they can be addressed, there is little problem for the results.
If I click SUBMIT double, then the value will double. What can this be overcome? Example Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrfmt.png

Comment: @Norax see update, changed `$results.append(html).show();` to `$results.html(html).show();`

Comment: Yes, this is better. Thanks :)

Comment: I need your help to fix some code that I have. But I do not know how to contact you. Please write something so that I can contact. Sorry if this disturbing, but I think you are the right person for the requested relief. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

For this:

> If I use jQuery auto submit $("test").Submit(); it works, but will switch to move the page.

maybe try:

```
 $("#test").submit(function(event) {
```

instead:

```
$(".search_button").click(function() {
```

Unfortunatelly I don't know what you want to really achieve.

Comment: Thanks, but it works the same way if using `$(".search_button").click(function () {`
I hope if visiting `britha.com/iklan/cari.php?search=KEYWORD` generate data.

Comment: `.submit()` would submit the form *and reload the page*....exactly what the OP said they did not want....it's even *in the comment you quoted*